# Can cooked chicken meat be edible if the carcass smells bad?

Tags: chicken

I roasted a whole chicken about 40 hours ago. I separated the carcass from the meat and stored them separately. The meat smells and tastes fine but the carcass smells weird and bad. Is it OK to eat the meat?

Comment: Hi Barb, and welcome to SA! Take a look at the [our](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help) pages when you get the chance. Could you tell us how you stored the meat and carcass?

Answer (score 1):

Chicken doesn't have a strong odor, so if you can smell any bad smell coming from a chicken, throw it away. Don't eat it and hope that you will be fine, because you can get really sick by eating off chicken. So no do not eat the rotten thing.